# mysql: simplify request - grouping by multi fields

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, multiple-columns

I have a table:

```
date, number, flag1, flag2, flag3
2015, 10,     1,    NULL, NULL
2015, 10,     1,    NULL, NULL
2015, 10,     0,    NULL, NULL
2015, 11,     1,    NULL,    NULL
2015, 11,     NULL, 1,    NULL
2015, 11,     NULL, 0,    NULL
2015, 12,     NULL, NULL, 0
2016, 10,     1,    NULL, NULL
2016, 11,     0,    NULL, NULL
2016, 13,     NULL, 1,    NULL
2016, 13,     NULL, NULL, 1
2016, 13,     NULL, NULL, 1
2016, 13,     NULL, NULL, 1
```

(NULL = 0)

I need to get the grouping of data by date:

```
date, flag1, flag2, flag3
2015, 2,     1      0
2016, 1,     1,     1
```

In details:

For each **date** is necessary to count the number of **flag1**, **flag2**, **flag3** whose flag = 1 and the same number

eg for flag1:

```
number = 10, flag1 = 1
number = 10, flag1 = 0
number = 10, flag1 = 1
number = 10, flag1 = 1
```

will count = 1

```
number = 10, flag1 = 1
number = 10, flag1 = 0
number = 11, flag1 = 1
number = 11, flag1 = 1
```

will count = 2

```
number = 10, flag1 = 0
number = 10, flag1 = 0
number = 11, flag1 = 1
number = 11, flag1 = 1
```

will count = 1

A wrote warking sql code, but it is difficult, slow, etc

```
SELECT
    date,
    SUM(count1) AS count1,
    SUM(count2) AS count2,
    SUM(count3) AS count3
FROM
(
    SELECT
        date,
        IF(SUM(flag1) <> 0, 1, 0) AS count1,
        IF(SUM(flag2) <> 0, 1, 0) AS count2,
        IF(SUM(flag3) <> 0, 1, 0) AS count3
    FROM
        table
--  WHERE
    GROUP BY
        number
) AS tmp
GROUP BY
    date
ORDER BY
    date;
```

**Prompt whether to simplify and speed up the code can be**

---

**Simplified**

```
SELECT
    date,
    SUM(count1) AS count1,
    SUM(count2) AS count2,
    SUM(count3) AS count3
FROM
(
    SELECT
        date,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(flag1)) AS count1,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(flag2)) AS count2,
        COUNT(DISTINCT(flag3)) AS count3
    FROM
        table
--  WHERE
    GROUP BY
        object_id
) AS tmp
GROUP BY
    date
ORDER BY
    date;
```

Comment: What if there's a fourth flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation of your original query:

```
SELECT `date`, 
       SUM(flag1=1) AS flag1,
       SUM(flag2=1) AS flag2,
       SUM(flag3=1) AS flag3
FROM (
   SELECT `date`, 
          MAX(flag1) AS flag1, 
          MAX(flag2) AS flag2,
          MAX(flag3) AS flag3
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY `date`, number) AS t
GROUP BY `date`   
ORDER BY `date`
```

You can try this out and see how it compares to the other query.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de01d0/1)

Comment: **Simplified**

 SELECT
  date,
        SUM(count1) AS count1,
        SUM(count2) AS count2,
        SUM(count3) AS count3
 FROM
    (
  SELECT
   date,
   COUNT(DISTINCT(flag1)) AS count1,
   COUNT(DISTINCT(flag2)) AS count2,
   COUNT(DISTINCT(flag3)) AS count3
  FROM
   table
 --  WHERE
  GROUP BY
   object_id
    ) AS tmp
    GROUP BY
  date
 ORDER BY
  date;

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you restructure your table to something like:

```
date, number, flag_no, flag_value
2015,     10,       1,          1
2015,     10,       1,          1
2015,     10,       1,          0
2015,     11,       1,          1
2016,     10,       1,          1
2016,     11,       1,          0
2015,     11,       2,          1
2015,     11,       2,          0
2016,     13,       2,          1
2015,     12,       3,          0
2016,     13,       3,          1
2016,     13,       3,          1
2016,     13,       3,          1
```